# Different width grid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, grid

I am trying to create a grid-layout like:
[image]

I do not want to use any `frameworks` or `apis` online and want to accomplish this using `pure CSS, HTML` and `JS` if needed. Here's what I tried:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

```
.grid{
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 120px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 200px 100px;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
.grid-item{
    background-color: #1EAAFC;
    background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, #6C52D9 0%, #1EAAFC 85%, #3EDFD7 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    grid-column: span 2;
    border: 6px solid #171717;
}
```

However, this leads me to:
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There are some subtle height differences in the items. Did you mean that or are the first two items in the first column to be the same height?

Comment: I mean the height differences. And thanks to everyone who answered below, I'll check the code soon and mark the one which helped me :)

Comment: The differences are very small (particularly the difference in width between the first two items in the first column, is that meant too? If you could put what the relative dimensions are to be then a grid could be formed, as it is we are guessing from your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This layout can be achieved using `grid-template-areas`

**The HTML would be:**

```html
<section class="grid">
    <div class="grid-area1"></div>
    <div class="grid-area2"></div>
    <div class="grid-area3"></div>
    <div class="grid-area4"></div>
    <div class="grid-area5"></div>
</section>
```

**The CSS for this would be:**

```css
 .grid {
    display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: [Margins] 0.2fr 1.9fr 0fr 3.5fr 0.2fr [Margins]; 
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 2.3fr 0.5fr 1.4fr 1.8fr 0.2fr; 
  gap: 10px 10px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    ". . . . ."
    ". grid-area1 . grid-area2 ."
    ". grid-area3 grid-area3 grid-area2 ."
    ". grid-area3 grid-area3 grid-area4 ."
    ". grid-area5 grid-area5 grid-area5 ."
    ". . . . ."; 
}

    .grid > * {
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
        color: #333;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        border: 6px solid #333;
}

.grid-area1 { grid-area: grid-area1; }
.grid-area2 { grid-area: grid-area2; }
.grid-area4 { grid-area: grid-area4; }
.grid-area5 { grid-area: grid-area5; }
.grid-area3 { grid-area: grid-area3; }
```

Output is:
[image: CSS Responsive Grid Design]

`This is a fully responsive layout, every single card can be made into its own separate grid container depending on the use case`

#### In accordance to [The Myth's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15042008/the-myth) request, a responsive version for mobile could be written as:

**CSS would be changed to:**

```css
    .grid {
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        margin-inline: 1rem;
        grid-template-areas:
            "grid-area1"
            "grid-area2"
            "grid-area3"
            "grid-area4"
            "grid-area5";
        gap: 10px 10px;
    }

    .grid>* {
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
        color: #333;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        border: 6px solid #333;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 38rem) {
        .grid {

            grid-template-columns: [Margins] 0.2fr 1.9fr 0fr 3.5fr 0.2fr [Margins];
            grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 2.3fr 0.5fr 1.4fr 1.8fr 0.2fr;

            grid-template-areas:
                ". . . . ."
                ". grid-area1 . grid-area2 ."
                ". grid-area3 grid-area3 grid-area2 ."
                ". grid-area3 grid-area3 grid-area4 ."
                ". grid-area5 grid-area5 grid-area5 ."
                ". . . . .";
        }


        .grid-area1 {
            grid-area: grid-area1;
        }

        .grid-area2 {
            grid-area: grid-area2;
        }

        .grid-area4 {
            grid-area: grid-area4;
        }

        .grid-area5 {
            grid-area: grid-area5;
        }

        .grid-area3 {
            grid-area: grid-area3;
        }
    }
```

**Output is**

[image: Mobile Version]

The transition from mobile to PC could be made smooth by
`.grid > * {transition: width .2s ease;}`

Comment: I'll give it a check but can you also tell me how to make each grid take `100% area` for mobile devices?

Comment: @TheMyth refer to the solution revision

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Html file to this

```html
<div class="gridprimary">
    <div class="gridprimary1">
         <div class="grid">
             <div class="grid-item"></div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="gridprimary1">
         <div class="grid">
             <div class="grid-item"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Change grid css
from:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

to:

```css
grid-template-columns: auto;
```

Add this to css file:

```css
.gridprimary {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```